# Google tag manager error sumome iframe

Tags: javascript, html, magento, iframe, google-tag-manager

This code is Google tag manager in my site:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (GTM) -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxx"
                  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (GTM) -->
```

I get this notice at the bottom on frontend:
More than one instance of Sumo is attempting to start on this page. Please check that you are only loading Sumo once per page.

I checked and I can see it has two

```
<iframe id="sumome-jquery-iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Why do I get this error? Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not per se a problem with GTM. The problem is, as stated in your error message, that your are starting more than one instance of [SumoMe](https://sumo.com/).

If this started after you installed GTM this probably because you have configured Sumo via GTM and accidentally fire the tag more than once per page. Check your tags and triggers, or set the Sumo tag to "fire only once per page" in the advanced tag settings.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it again.